# how to subtract 5 days from current date

Tags: python-3.x

I want to subtract 5 days from current date

code:

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
end_date = datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=5)
```

when I print end_date I am getting error like :

```
   an integer is required (got type datetime.date)
```

Comment: The Code is working, there is no error...Checked on python 3.7.3 version.

Answer (score 1):

from datetime import date, timedelta

date.today() - timedelta(5)